# How to strike out over an environment and formulas and using local variables in latex?

Tags: environments, ulem, environment-variables

While I am revising my papers, for the sake of easier tracking and saving the time of the reviewers, and hence shortening the review process (I hope!), I use the following commands

```
\usepackage{ulem}
\normalem
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\add}[1]{\textcolor{Green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\del}[1]{\textcolor{Red}{\sout{#1}}}
\newcommand{\addf}[1]{\textcolor{Green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\delf}[1]{\textcolor{Red}{\overline{#1}}}
```

These commands are quite well. However, there are some points as follow:

1- If I delete an environment, say a definition, the output is not generated, I get errors. For example, suppose I use `\del` around the following environment

```
\begin{definition}[\cite{zhu_three_2007}]
    Let $(U,\mathbf{C})$ be a covering approximation space and $X \subseteq U$.
    $$ \int f(x) , $$
\end{definition}
```

This creates a bunch of errors! When I comment the command `[\cite{....}]`, the PDF is generated! However, the definition is not appeared at the output and the file is still full of errors!

When I remove the `\begin{definition}` and `\end{definition}`, the error `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. }` vanishes, but the file has still errors!

When I comment the line containing `$$ \int f(x) , $$`, there are no errors! But I do not have my desired output!

I have found the solution for striking over the formulas in this way `\newcommand{\delf}[1]{\textcolor{Red}{\overline{#1}}}`, however, how can I fix this. In other words, **using a single command to draw a red line over the text, including the environment name and formulas?**

2- Even if this gets fixed, I think another thing also can happen! Although I mean to delete it, by striking it out, it affects the numbering, i.e. it is counted in the definitions' counter. I do not know if we can use `local` variables as in `C++` or other programming languages to override this situation. **It would be great if I can create a command like `\del[counter_name=counter_value]{......}`, which does the same thing as above, but does not change anything out!**

Sorry for writing a lot!

Edited: The following is a minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pr}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{\bf Remark}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{ulem}
\normalem
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\add}[1]{\textcolor{Green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\del}[1]{\textcolor{Red}{\sout{#1}}}
\newcommand{\addf}[1]{\textcolor{Green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\delf}[1]{\textcolor{Red}{\overline{#1}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{definition}[\cite{zhu_three_2007}]
        Let $(U,\mathbf{C})$ be a covering approximation space and $X \subseteq U$.
    $$ \int f(x) , $$
    \end{definition}

    \del{\begin{definition}[\cite{zhu_three_2007}]
        Let $(U,\mathbf{C})$ be a covering approximation space and $X \subseteq U$.
    $$ \int f(x) , $$
    \end{definition}}

    \add{\begin{definition}[\cite{zhu_three_2007}]
        Let $(U,\mathbf{C})$ be a covering approximation space and $X \subseteq U$.
    $$ \int f(x) , $$
    \end{definition}}

    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{zhu_three_2007}
        W.~Zhu, F.-Y. Wang, On three types of covering-based rough sets, {IEEE}
          Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering 19~(8) (2007) 1131--1144.
    \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example with the definitions of `{definition}` environment etc. I think this is an issue with the optional argument of the `definition` environment.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the comment. I have updated the post to add a minimal working example (although it's not working :) )

Comment: Sorry, I can't compile your update -- there are other issues with the bibliography.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It cannot be compiled as I said, unless you comment the `[\cite{zhu_three_2007}]` and `$$ \int f(x) , $$` in the second definition.

Comment: Ok, I'll try again. By the way: Don't use `$$...$$`. That's outdated syntax. Use `\[ ... \]` instead

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. You also need to comment out the `\usepackage{natbib}`.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that `natbib` is a culprit

Comment: sorry but why `\sout`? `\textcolor` isn't suffisante?

Comment: for 2 point you can try `\newsavebox\mtbox
\newcommand{\Del}[1]{\sbox\mtbox{\vbox{#1}}}`

Comment: @touhami Unfortunately, no. Since the reviewers print the paper in black and white. If this happens, then the added and removed texts are not distinguishable.

Comment: may be a solution http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=102